# how to point to a logback.xml file in my project among many

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, classpath, logback

i am trying to send emails in my project using smtp appender through logback.xml.
i have 2 logback.xml files in different paths in the same project
one file is under WEB-INF/lib/logback.xml and the other is udner WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml
In my project i have to point to WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml to get the emails  but i should not remove the one in lib directory as it is used by some other one.
could you please help hoe to fix this.
this is all done in linux to deploy a web server using tomact.

Answer (score 1):

Set system property **logback.configurationFile** passing in the path of config file.

```
logback.configurationFile=/path to config file
```